# Angular Deployment using Azure Devops doesn't load -- shows "hey node developers!" page

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to deploy an angular app to Azure, the deployment seems to work, the artifacts look correct, however when I go to the website I am shown the default Azure "hey node developers" page. See (http://testss-123.azurewebsites.net/)

My build pipeline is as follows:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

and my deployment pipeline is the default "Deploy a Node.js app to Azure App Service"
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNwCF.png)

I have tried this both with an actual app, and also with the default app built buy "ng new"

Comment: Would you please share your latest information about this issue?Could you solve the issue through Levi‘s solution ? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to solve this problem, however as a workaround I deployed the app in a docker container, with the following dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest AS node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install && \
    npm run build-prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/superselection/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=node /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

the following nginx conf file in my src folder:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

and finally the following build pipeline:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: XXXXXXXX
    azureContainerRegistry: XXXXXXXX
    defaultContext: false
    context: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: XXXXXXXX
    azureContainerRegistry: XXXXXXXX
    action: 'Push an image'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure WebApp is running on an IIS instance by default. If you want to handle the Html5 Mode(without the hashbang) then you have to create a Web.Config file and define a rewrite.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="index.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://slides.com/sajeetharan/angular-continuous-integration#/11

Comment: I've tried this, (and added it to the angular.json) and still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you login http://testss-123.scm.azurewebsites.net/. You will probably find your code was deployed to folder `site/wwwroot/dist/yourapp`, install of `site/wwwroot`. It might cause this issue.

You can modify your archiveFiles task as below. Point the **rootFolderOrFile** to the **app-name** folder under **dist** folder. And set **includeRootFolder** to false.

so that the output zip file only contain your ready-to-deploy code.

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/<yourapp>'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

Comment: I attempted to do this, but still didn't have any luck. In the end I managed to get around the issue by deploying the app in a docker container.

Comment: @Joe Bucklkey. That's great you work it around, Did you make any changes to your yaml when deploying to docker container? It would be appreciated if you could share the your steps to do this.

Comment: see answer below